# How do I set the title for an XAML Page container?

Tags: c++-winrt

I want to set the title on an XAML page with an XAML Page container.  There is no "Title" or "WindowTitle" tag for Page.  However, when run, the VS project name, XAML_001, appears in the title area.  How do I set my own title?

I have tried using what I know from C#/WPF which uses an XAML Window container which does have a "Title" tag.  But, this does not work for a VS 2017 Blank App (C++/WinRT).

```
<Page
    x:Class="XAML_001.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:XAML_001"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="myButton" Click="ClickHandler">Click You</Button>

    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

I cannot figure out how to change the title.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the title which appears in the Windows Title Bar for the C++/WinRT, XAML application is set in the Package.appxmanifest file, “Application” tab in the “Display name” text box.

For reasons of which I am unaware, the "Title" property is not in the Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls Page Class as it is for C#, WPF applications.